# phpseclib csr and key generation

Tags: php, phpseclib

I am using phpseclib to create private key,public key and csr but i couldnt work out where I can specify the keysize and signaturealgorithm.. by default they are 1024bit and sha1WithRSAEncryption however I would like to specify a stronger combination.

According to the documentation here http://phpseclib.bantux.org/api/master/phpseclib/File/X509.html it only has examples for Sha1

signCSR($signatureAlgorithm = 'sha1WithRSAEncryption')

thanks in advance!

Comment: I should add, simply modifying to `'sha2WithRSAEncryption'` does not work and results in this error. **Notice: Invalid OID in C:\xampp\htdocs\labs\test2\phpseclib\File\ASN1.php on line 1038**

Comment: okay, found the correct string `'sha256WithRSAEncryption'`. A complete list of acceptable algorithms can be found here [link](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/intro.html). So now just need to know how to specify the key size 2048, 4096 etc..

Comment: ok found it using google.. would of been nice if it was documented on the official site though. from this createKey() to -> createKey($bits=2048)

Answer (score 1):

To specify the keysize use: **createKey($bits=2048)**

To specify the sig algorithm use: **signCSR($signatureAlgorithm = 'sha1WithRSAEncryption')**

Use one of the following supported algorithms:

- md2WithRSAEncryption
- md5WithRSAEncryption
- sha1WithRSAEncryption
- sha224WithRSAEncryption
- sha256WithRSAEncryption
- sha384WithRSAEncryption
- sha512WithRSAEncryption